# Symbol | in view for Flask tutorial

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm doing a tutorial for the Flask framework at http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms In this very chapter I've found a piece of code that I didn't understand. It is:

```
|{% for pr in providers %}
<a href="javascript:set_openid('{{pr.url}}', '{{pr.name}}');">{{pr.name}}</a> |
{% endfor %}
```

Why do we need the symbol | there?

Comment: it's the literal character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pipe is simply adding the `|` between providers, as seen in the screenshot. Notice the symbol between "Google" and "Yahoo"

[image: Pipes]

Pipes are used in [filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters), but for this specific example, that is not how they are used.